# Подключение javaScript

Tags: jquery, javascript

Подключаю jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Хочу грузить из своей машины локальную копию библиотеки jQuery, если удаленная недоступна. Помню, где-то на просторах сети видел способ метод это осуществить. Не подскажите?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="/js/jquery.dev.js"><'+'/script>');</script>
```

Comment: наверное, немного нагляднее  использовать window.jQuery || 
вместо !window.jQuery &&

Comment: Кому как, дело вкуса.